# Does there exist on compact metric space an uncountable set of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be metric compact space and $\mu$ be a positive, finite, atomless, regular measure on $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$. Does  there exist a set $C\subset X$ such that $C$ is uncountable and of $\mu$-measure zero?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109380/a-uncountable-thus-mua0

Comment: I imagine you want to start with an uncountable metric space?

Comment: Yes. For countable $X$ the measure $\mu$ would have an atom.

Comment: Ah, silly me...

Comment: @CarlMummert. This is a bit different since the other does not assume any regularity conditions on the measure.

Comment: @azarel: I put an answer below which I think shows the parallel between the answer to the other question and the answer to this one.

Comment: Every finite measure on the Borel sets of a metric space is automatically regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An uncountable compact metric space contains a homeomorphic copy $C$ of the Cantor space, and $C$ is Borel in the original space. The Cantor space can be decomposed into uncountably many disjoint, uncountable, Borel subsets (because $C \cong C\times C$). If all of these had positive measure, some infinite number would all have measure larger than $1/n$ for some fixed $n$, which is impossible because the original measure was finite.

(This is similar to the answer by azarel but easier.)

Comment: I believe azarel answered first, so really the credit should be his.

Answer (score 4):

There is a subset $A$ of the Cantor set $C$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$ so that $\mu(A)=0$ for all non-atmoic Borel measure on the Cantor set. On the other hand, since $X$ is uncountable, there is a homeomorphic copy of the Cantor set inside $X$ hence the copy of $A$ inside $X$ must have measure zero.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the first sentence?

Comment: @JonasMeyer. Lemma 2.1.21 in Walks on ordinals and their characteristics by Stevo Todorcevic